# How to use vim.bo.syntax with StrikeoutMatch in Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

How to convert this:

```
" txt strikeout ~~ (background black) ~~
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt   syntax match StrikeoutMatch /\~\~.*\~\~/
hi def  StrikeoutColor   ctermbg=016 ctermfg=black
hi link StrikeoutMatch StrikeoutColor
```

To neovim lua using probably `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd`, I would like to prevent using:

```lua
vim.cmd([[
  augroup StrikeoutMatch
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.txt syntax match StrikeoutMatch /\~\~.*\~\~/
  augroup END
]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Autocmd Functions" in [Neovim API](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html) to use `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd` and `vim.api.nvim_set_hl` to set Highlight groups.

To set your pattern/regexp, you could use VIM function `matchadd` via `vim.fn.matchadd`.

You could convert your code in Lua:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({'BufRead', 'BufNewFile'}, {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('StrikeoutMatch', { clear = true }),
  pattern = { '*.txt' },
  callback = function()
    vim.fn.matchadd('StrikeoutMatch', '\\~\\~.*\\~\\~')
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'StrikeoutColor', { bg=016, fg='Black' })
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'StrikeoutMatch', { link='StrikeoutColor' })
  end,
})
```